# Using hyperref with includegraphics doesn't work with XeLaTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, hyperref

I'm trying to create a hyperlinked image with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \href{https://www.wikipedia.org/}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{img.png}} % For any img.png
\end{document}
```

When compiling with `xelatex` the link isn't produced on the image, but compiling it with `pdflatex` does make it clickable. Do I need to pass any special argument to the packages to make them work with `xelatex` or is it just an impossible task?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a known and long-standing `(x)dvipdfmx` bug, see https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/25/#c0f5. Currently only pdf images are supported.

Comment: I see, I just used `convert` on the image and can confirm it compiles with `xelatex`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

With a new dvipdfmx (e.g. dvipdfmx Version 20200902) it will work directly, the detection of link boxes has been improved. I got the new binary from w32tex.org and could already test it. It will be in the next texlive.

With older versions you can use `\XeTeXLinkBox` (defined by hyperref):

```
\href{https://www.wikipedia.org/}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image.png}}}
```